# Session views helper CakePHP3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This is my code in my view:

```
if($this->request->session->read('Auth.User')) {
    echo $this->Html->link('Log Out', array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'logout'));
}
if(!$this->request->session->read('Auth.User')) {
    echo $this->Html->link('Log Out', array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'logout'));
}
```

But I get this error:

`Call to a member function read() on null`

I'm connected but is dont work.

Comment: have you used `Cake\View\Helper\SessionHelper` in your controller ?

Comment: @MohdSayeed yes is in my AppController

Comment: try this `$this->request->session()->read('Auth.User')` Here you have [more info](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-the-session-object)

Comment: @JacekBBudzynski this is my code, but not working...

Comment: Your code is wrong :replace with `$this->request->session()->read('Auth.User')` to this code `$this->request->session->read('Auth.User')`

Answer (score 0):

**You can try another way for checking `Authenticate User` from your `View`**

*From your `AppController` you can set `$AuthUser` variable*

**Example:**

```
public function initialize(){
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
       #All configurations for AuthComponent
    ]);

    $this->set('AuthUser',$this->Auth->user()); #Set for all Views
}
```

> **Note :** Now you can use `$AuthUser` variable to your `View` directly.